# Recursively re-spawn file on fsnotify Remove/Rename (Golang)

Tags: linux, go, concurrency, filesystems

The Goal:

I am attempting to monitor a file that is subject to being moved or deleted at any time. If and when it is, I'd like to re-generate this file so that an app can continue to write to it.

Attempted:

I have attempted to do this by implementing two functions, `monitorFile()` to listen for `fsnotify` events and send the removed filename over a channel to `listen()` which upon receiving the filepath string over un-buffered channel `mvrm` (move or rename), will recursively re-generate the file.

Observed behavior:

I can `echo 'foo' >> ./inlogs/test.log` and see a write notification, and can even `rm ./inlogs/test.log` (or `mv`) and see that the file is re-generated... but only once. If I `rm` or `mv` the file a second time, the file is not re-generated.

- Strangely, the undesired behavior does not occur on local Mac OSx (System Version: macOS 10.13.2 (17C88), Kernel Version: Darwin 17.3.0), but does on two different Linux machines with builds:

Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Linux 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Diagnostics Attempted:

The differing behavior makes me think I have a race condition. However `go build -race` provides no output.

I wonder if `done` chan is receiving due to such a race condition?

Apologies that this is not 'Playground-able', but any advice or observation of where this might by racy or buggy would be welcome.

watcher.go:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "log"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

//Globals
var mvrm chan string

func main() {
    mvrm = make(chan string)
    listen(mvrm)
    monitorFile("./inlogs/test.log", mvrm)
}

func listen(mvrm chan string) {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case fileName := <-mvrm :
                fmt.Println(fileName)
                newFile, err := os.OpenFile(fileName, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND , 0666)
                if err == nil {
                    defer newFile.Close()

                    // Recursively re-spawn monitoring
                    go listen(mvrm)
                    go monitorFile(fileName, mvrm)
                } else {
                    log.Fatal("Err re-spawning file")
                }
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
    }()
}

func monitorFile(filepath string, mvrm chan string) {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                switch event.Op {
                case fsnotify.Write :
                    log.Println("Write!")
                    continue
                case fsnotify.Chmod :
                    log.Println("Chmod!")
                    continue
                case fsnotify.Remove, fsnotify.Rename :
                    log.Println("Moved or Deleted!")
                    mvrm <- event.Name
                    continue
                default:
                    log.Printf("Unknown: %v\n", event.Op)
                    continue
                }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("Error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = watcher.Add(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

EDIT:

With some great feedback, I've paired this down. In Linux it is now re-generating the file as intended, but after monitoring with `top`, I see it is spawning a new PID every time the file is moved or deleted, so I do still have a leak. Suggestions as to how I might eliminate this behavior welcome.

https://play.golang.org/p/FrlkktoK2-s

Comment: in your `listen()` take the `default: continue` out, in fact the whole select just keep the code under `case`. otherwise your for goes into the infinite. Check your `top` you'll see high CPU usage.

Comment: and whole recursive thing leaks `go routines` and open files since `defer newFile.Close()` never gets to run, since your `for` never breaks and you never return from `go func(){}()`

Comment: and you don't really need `listen` to be a go routine, all you need is simple function to create new file under your `Remove, Rename` case.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @biosckon. I agree with the approach of pairing down to the minimal number of routines required. This latest edit is behaving as expected now on Linux, but I do suspect I may still have the leaks you described after monitoring cpu with `htop`. Would you be so kind as to please take a look? https://play.golang.org/p/FrlkktoK2-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the code comments, most of the discussion in code comments.

https://play.golang.com/p/qxq58h1nQjp

Outside the golang universe, but facebook has a tool that does pretty much what you are looking for, just not as much go code fun :): https://github.com/facebook/watchman

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    // couldn't find the go-fsnotify, this is what pops up on github
    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

func main() {
    monitorFile("./inlogs/test.log")
}

func monitorFile(filepath string) {

    // starting watcher
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    // monitor events
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                switch event.Op {
                case fsnotify.Create:
                    log.Println("Created")

                case fsnotify.Write:
                    log.Println("Write")

                case fsnotify.Chmod:
                    log.Println("Chmod")

                case fsnotify.Remove, fsnotify.Rename:
                    log.Println("Moved or Deleted")

                    respawnFile(event.Name)

                    // add the file back to watcher, since it is removed from it
                    // when file is moved or deleted
                    log.Printf("add to watcher file:  %s\n", filepath)
                    // add appears to be concurrently safe so calling from multiple go routines is ok
                    err = watcher.Add(filepath)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }

                    // there is  not need to break the loop
                    // we just continue waiting for events from the same watcher

                }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("Error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    // add file to the watcher first time
    log.Printf("add to watcher 1st: %s\n", filepath)
    err = watcher.Add(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // to keep waiting forever, to prevent main exit
    // this is to replace the done channel
    select {}
}

func respawnFile(filepath string) {
    log.Printf("re creating file %s\n", filepath)

    // you just need the os.Create()
    respawned, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Err re-spawning file: %v", filepath)
    }
    defer respawned.Close()

    // there is no need to call monitorFile again, it never returns
    // the call to "go monitorFile(filepath)" was causing another go routine leak
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: yes! These comments are the insight I was looking for, and clearly show where I was doing assumptive reasoning about the state of my overwrought non-solution. Now studying this approach, I see the effect of re-adding the watcher in `Remove, Rename`, while not `break`ing. Cool use of `select{}` too, to prevent `main` from exiting!  And, now comparing to my attempt, I see clearly where my leak was. Only wish `-race` could warn us about leaks! Sincere thanks for taking the time, I'm going to take your approach in framing up my next dive into using routines, wherever that may be.

Comment: I’m happy this helped. I also removed the ‘continue’ statements. And added the “Create” clause for completeness. Happy new year:)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so I will pretend this to be an answer.

On Linux, fsnotify use inotify to monitor fs changes, which means calling every add will run a syscall to create a new process and that's why you see it spawning PIDs.

If that is a problem to you, it is also a common practice to monitor the dir of the file and filter events related to it. It means less syscall but more go code. Pick it yourself.